# I wanted to modify the response of my array to different format

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mapreduce, reduce

I wanted to modify the response of my array to different format.
I have below response from database.

```
let response = [
    {
        "team_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "participant1": 98,
        "participant2": 99,
        "participant3": 100,
        "participant4": 101,
        "phase1": 0,
        "phase2": 0,
        "phase3": 0,
        "phase4": 0,
        "phase5": 0
    },
    {
        "team_id": 2,
        "team_name": "Skywalkers",
        "participant1": 102,
        "participant2": 103,
        "participant3": 104,
        "participant4": null,
        "phase1": 0,
        "phase2": 0,
        "phase3": 0,
        "phase4": 0,
        "phase5": 0
    }
]
```

And I want to modify like below :-

```
[
    {
        "team_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "participantDetails":[{"participant1": 98},
        {"participant2": 99},
        {"participant3": 100},
        {"participant4": 101}],
        "phase1": 0,
        "phase2": 0,
        "phase3": 0,
        "phase4": 0,
        "phase5": 0
    },
    {
        "team_id": 2,
        "team_name": "Skywalkers",
        "participantDetails": [{"participant1": 102},
        {"participant2": 103},
        {"participant3": 104},
        {"participant4": null}],
        "phase1": 0,
        "phase2": 0,
        "phase3": 0,
        "phase4": 0,
        "phase5": 0
    }
]
```

I have tried with map, reduce but not getting expected response.
Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried with `.reduce()` or `.map()`?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+group+object+array+entries+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Loop through the array, loop through keys of object and check if the key `startsWith` participant, create an object and push it to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map & inside callback function check if the key name starts with `participant`. If so then put that key value pain in an array and delete the key value from original object

```js
let response = [{
    "team_id": 1,
    "team_name": "Avengers",
    "participant1": 98,
    "participant2": 99,
    "participant3": 100,
    "participant4": 101,
    "phase1": 0,
    "phase2": 0,
    "phase3": 0,
    "phase4": 0,
    "phase5": 0
  },
  {
    "team_id": 2,
    "team_name": "Skywalkers",
    "participant1": 102,
    "participant2": 103,
    "participant3": 104,
    "participant4": null,
    "phase1": 0,
    "phase2": 0,
    "phase3": 0,
    "phase4": 0,
    "phase5": 0
  }
]
const data = response.map((elem) => {
  const participantDetails = [];
  for (let keys in elem) {
    if (keys.startsWith('participant')) {
      participantDetails.push({
        [keys]: elem[keys]
      })
      delete elem[keys]
    }
  }
  return {
    ...elem,
    participantDetails
  }
});
console.log(data)
```